# Merge Account dashboard with Account information

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, css, customer-account

How can I move my Account Dashboard information to Account Information (merge them together)
I want to show:

- Contact Information
- Default Billing Address
- Default Shipping Address
- Account Information

In same page instead of 2 page (account dashboard and account information)